# Multi-input NetGraph configurations with Pytorch

Tags: neural-network, pytorch

I'm working on an advanced reinforcement learning problem with `PyTorch` and the environment we'd like to present to the agent consists of 3 inputs mapping to a 245-length vector of possible actions.

**Inputs**
1 - Vector 1D
2 - Matrix 2D
3 - Matrix 2D

**Output**
243 length 1D Vector

This configuration is trivial to achieve with Wolfram Matheamtica's `NetGraph` function and I have it working with synthetic training data using an association in the format of `<|"vec"->data, 'mat1'->data, 'mat2'->data, 'Output'->data|>`

[image: Mathematica Image]

There is a lot of backend and frontend coding already completed in Python and I'd like to try to use this project to get better at PyTorch. Is such a configuration is possible? I thought I was ok at PyTorch I'm striking out at how to achieve such a network in PyTorch. We've been through the docs and lots of Google searches and nothing seems to be coming up for how to construct this type of network. Github Copilot and ChatGPT were similarly unhelpful.

Do anyone have any suggestions for how this type of network architecture is achieved in PyTorch?